# I can't boot ubuntu normally

Tags: 14.04, boot

I downloaded and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from a usb stick and erased windows 8. It worked but when I turn off the pc it doesnt load up it just keeps turning the fan in loops as if it is trying to load but can't.

I can only get in by going to setup and there are four system file names. Ubuntu and Ubuntu recover mode twice, both the same.

I have tried a few things but to no avail.

If anyone could tell me how to resolve this boot issue or whatever is causing my system to not load I would be very grateful

Comment: can you get into BIOS?

Comment: Yes I can get into BIOS

Comment: Do you have an option for 'legacy boot' or something similar?

Comment: Yes I can change it to that. Do you know what that would do?

Comment: Ubuntu sometimes requires legacy boot. If in Bios you have a 'boot menu' and after enabling legacy it contains 'ubuntu' and 'Ubuntu Legacy' as two different boot options choose 'Ubuntu Legacy'

Comment: It didn't work when I changed it to legacy boot mode. The only way I can get into Ubuntu is holding the shift key when I turn on the pc and going to advanced options then selecting ubuntu. It looks like it has installed twice because there are two ubuntu systems , with same name and two ubuntu recovery mode systems with same name.

Comment: I did a complete re-install from a usb stick and changed the boot settings to legacy. This has worked so thank you. Regards

Comment: hmm. re-install not exactly an option for many people. I'll do some further research to see what on can do without reinstalling. But glad it worked